# Processing 2 Sketch

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, processing

I'm working on a processing sketch [here](https://github.com/davidcool/processing/tree/master/polyhedrons/polyhedrons_4).

Main sketch:

```
/*
polyhedrons 3

david cool
http://davidcool.com
http://generactive.net
http://mystic.codes

April, 2015

based on:
Spherical Coordinates Tutorial File
April, 2008
blprnt@blprnt.com
*/

//import processing.opengl.*; // not needed for processing 3 ???
import java.util.*;

float zoom = 0.025;
boolean toggle = true;
ArrayList<Sphere> spheres = new ArrayList<Sphere>();
PFont f;

void setup() {
  //code here is executed once, when the app initializes
  size(displayWidth,displayHeight,OPENGL);
  smooth();
  lights();
  background(0);
  frameRate(30);
  noCursor();
  //create an instance of the Sphere Class
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    spheres.add(new Sphere());
    spheres.get(i).radius = 200;
  }
  f = createFont("Arial",16,true);
};

void draw() {
  noCursor();
  background(0);
  pointLight(200, 200, 200, width/2, height/2, 200);
  ambientLight(102, 102, 102);
  spotLight(51, 102, 126, 80, 20, 40, -1, 0, 0, PI/2, 2);
  for (Sphere s: spheres) {
    pushMatrix();
    s.update();
    s.render();
    popMatrix();
  }
  if (toggle) {
    textFont(f,24); 
    fill(255);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text("Left click to add polyhedrons, right click to destroy!",width/2,height/2 - 25);
    text("Use the mouse wheel or trackpad up/down scroll to zoom.",width/2,height/2 + 25);
  }
};

void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    toggle = false;
    spheres.get(0).addSphereItem("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron");
    spheres.get(1).addSphereItem("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron");
    spheres.get(2).addSphereItem("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron");
    spheres.get(3).addSphereItem("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron");
    spheres.get(4).addSphereItem("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron");
  } else if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    spheres.get(0).removeSphereItem();
    spheres.get(1).removeSphereItem();
    spheres.get(2).removeSphereItem();
    spheres.get(3).removeSphereItem();
    spheres.get(4).removeSphereItem();
  }

};

void mouseWheel(MouseEvent e) {
  zoom += map(e.getCount(), -10, 10, 0.001, -0.001);
  zoom = constrain(zoom, 0.00001, 1.5);
};

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') {
    spheres.clear();
    setup();
  }
  if (key == CODED) {
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    } 
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    }
    if (keyCode == UP) {
    } 
  }
};
```

Sphere class:

```
class Sphere {

  float xPos = random(200,width-200);                //X Position of the Sphere
  float yPos = random(200,height-200);                 //Y Position of the Sphere
  float zPos = random(-500,500);                    //Z Position of the Sphere
  float radius = 300;                  //Radius of the Sphere    
  ArrayList<Polyhedron> items = new ArrayList<Polyhedron>();   //List of all of the items contained in the Sphere
  String type;

  public Sphere() {
    //Empty, for now!
  };

  public void addSphereItem() {
    Polyhedron si = new SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron();
    //Set random values for the spherical coordinates
    si.positionSphere(radius, random(PI * 2), random(PI * 2));
    //scale
    si.scaleFactor(5000);
    //fill
    si.fillColor(int(random(255)), int(random(255)), int(random(255)), 30);
    //stroke
    si.noStrokeToggle(true);
    //si.strokeColor(int(random(255)), int(random(255)), int(random(255)), 255);
    //Add the new sphere item to the end of our ArrayList
    items.add(items.size(), si);
  };

  public void addSphereItem(String _type) {
    type = _type;
    if (type.equals("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron") == true) {
      Polyhedron si = new SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron();
      //Set random values for the spherical coordinates
      si.positionSphere(radius, random(PI * 2), random(PI * 2));
      //scale
      si.scaleFactor(5000);
      //fill
      si.fillColor(int(random(255)), int(random(255)), int(random(255)), 30);
      //stroke
      si.noStrokeToggle(true);
      //si.strokeColor(int(random(255)), int(random(255)), int(random(255)), 255);
      //Add the new sphere item to the end of our ArrayList
      items.add(items.size(), si);
    }
  };

  public void removeSphereItem() {
    if (items.size() != 0) {
      items.remove((items.size()-1));
    } 
    if (items.size() == 0){
      toggle = true;
    }
  };

  public void update() {
    for (Polyhedron p: items) {
      p.update();
    };
  };

  public void render() {
    //Move to the center point of the sphere
    translate(xPos, yPos, zPos);
    //Mark our position in 3d space
    pushMatrix();
    //noFill();
    //stroke(255,255,255,100);
    //strokeWeight(1);
    //sphere(280);
    //Render each GreatStellatedDodecahedron
    for (Polyhedron p: items) {
      p.rotate(radians(random(-0.08,0.08)-frameCount%360), radians(random(-0.05,0.05)+frameCount%360), 0);
      p.render();
    };
    //Go back to our original position in 3d space
    popMatrix();
  };

};
```

`Polyhedron` abstract class:

```
/*
Polyhedron abstract class

david cool
http://davidcool.com
http://generactive.net
http://mystic.codes
*/

public abstract class Polyhedron {
    // position
  public float x = 0;
  public float y = 0;
  public float z = 0;
  //Spherical Coordinates
  public boolean parentSphere = false;
  public float radius;
  public float theta;
  public float phi;
  public float r;
  //Speed properties
  public float thetaSpeed = random(-0.01, 0.01);
  public float phiSpeed = random(-0.01, 0.01);
  //Stray
  public float stray = random(2,-2);
  // scale
  public float scaleSize = 5000;
  // rotation
  public boolean rotate = true;
  public float rx = 0;
  public float ry = 0;
  public float rz = 0;
  // fill
  public boolean nofill = false;
  public int fc0 = 255;
  public int fc1 = 255;
  public int fc2 = 255;
  public int fc3 = 255;
  // stroke
  public boolean nostroke = false;
  public float sw = 0.01;
  public int sc0 = 0;
  public int sc1 = 0;
  public int sc2 = 0;
  public int sc3 = 255;

  public void position(float _x, float _y, float _z) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    z = _z;
  }

  public void positionSphere(float _radius, float _theta, float _phi) {
    parentSphere = true;
    radius = _radius;
    theta = _theta;
    phi = _phi;
  }

  public void speed(float _thetaSpeed, float _phiSpeed) {
    thetaSpeed = _thetaSpeed;
    phiSpeed = _phiSpeed;
  }

  public void strayFactor(float _stray) {
    stray = _stray;
  }

  public void scaleFactor(float _scaleSize) {
    scaleSize = _scaleSize;  
  }

  public void fillColor(int _fc0, int _fc1, int _fc2, int _fc3) {
    fc0 = _fc0;
    fc1 = _fc1;
    fc2 = _fc2;
    fc3 = _fc3;
  }

  public void noFillToggle(boolean _nofill) {
    nofill = _nofill;
  }

  public void strokeColor(int _sc0, int _sc1, int _sc2, int _sc3) {
    sc0 = _sc0;
    sc1 = _sc1;
    sc2 = _sc2;
    sc3 = _sc3;
  }

  public void noStrokeToggle(boolean _nostroke) {
    nostroke = _nostroke;
  }

  public void strokeColorWeight(float _sw) {
    sw = _sw;
  }

  public void rotate(float _rx, float _ry, float _rz) {
    rx = _rx;
    ry = _ry;
    rz = _rz;
  }

  public void update() {
    theta += thetaSpeed;
    phi += phiSpeed;
  }

  abstract String name();

  abstract void render();

} //end Polyhedron class
```

Specific `Polyhedron` class:

```
/*
SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron class

david cool
http://davidcool.com
http://generactive.net
http://mystic.codes
*/

public class SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron extends Polyhedron {

  // polyhedron
  final int FACES = 60;     // number of faces 
  final int VERTICES = 6;   // VERTICES per face
  final float C0  = 0.185914468266304889629526215104;    //(2 * sqrt(3 + 2 * sqrt(5)) - 1 - sqrt(5)) / 12
  final float C1  = 0.267843693395936526330702957199;    //(1 - sqrt(5) + sqrt(2 * (3 * sqrt(5) - 1))) / 8
  final float C2  = 0.300815928655245048550759325631;    //(sqrt(2 * (19 + 9 * sqrt(5))) - 3 - sqrt(5)) / 12
  final float C3  = 0.309016994374947424102293417183;    //(sqrt(5) - 1) / 4 
  final float C4  = 0.433380199586931046495436031247;    //(sqrt(3 + 2 * sqrt(5)) - 1) / 4 
  final float C5  = 0.576860687770883950432996374382;    //(sqrt(5) - 1 + sqrt(2 * (3 * sqrt(5) - 1))) / 8 
  final float C6  = 0.809016994374947424102293417183;    //(1 + sqrt(5)) / 4 
  final float C7  = 0.933380199586931046495436031247;    //(1 + sqrt(3 + 2 * sqrt(5))) / 4 
  final float C8  = 1.01024088735781499692843240563;     //(sqrt(5) - 3 + sqrt(2 * (19 + 9 * sqrt(5)))) / 8 
  final float C9  = 1.201223892982867572826138988446;    //(3 - sqrt(5) + sqrt(2 * (19 + 9 * sqrt(5)))) / 8 
  final float C10 = 1.30901699437494742410229341718;     //(3 + sqrt(5)) / 4 
  final float C11 = 1.36676039917386209299087206249;     //sqrt(3 + 2 * sqrt(5)) / 2      
  private PVector[] vert = new PVector[112]; // list of ve//rtices
  private int[][] faces =  new int[FACES][VERTICES];  // list of faces (joining vertices)

  private SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron() {   
    // set vertices
    vert[  0] = new PVector(   C3,  0.0, -C11 );
    vert[  1] = new PVector(   C3,  0.0,  C11 );
    vert[  2] = new PVector(  -C3,  0.0, -C11 );
    vert[  3] = new PVector(  -C3,  0.0,  C11 );
    vert[  4] = new PVector( -C11,   C3,  0.0 );
    vert[  5] = new PVector( -C11,  -C3,  0.0 );
    vert[  6] = new PVector(  C11,   C3,  0.0 );
    vert[  7] = new PVector(  C11,  -C3,  0.0 );
    vert[  8] = new PVector(  0.0, -C11,   C3 );
    vert[  9] = new PVector(  0.0, -C11,  -C3 );
    vert[ 10] = new PVector(  0.0,  C11,   C3 );
    vert[ 11] = new PVector(  0.0,  C11,  -C3 );
    vert[ 12] = new PVector(  0.0,  0.5,  C10 );
    vert[ 13] = new PVector(  0.0,  0.5,  C10 );
    vert[ 14] = new PVector(  0.0,  0.5, -C10 );
    vert[ 15] = new PVector(  0.0,  0.5, -C10 );
    vert[ 16] = new PVector(  0.0, -0.5,  C10 );
    vert[ 17] = new PVector(  0.0, -0.5,  C10 );
    vert[ 18] = new PVector(  0.0, -0.5, -C10 );
    vert[ 19] = new PVector(  0.0, -0.5, -C10 );
    vert[ 20] = new PVector(  C10,  0.0,  0.5 );
    vert[ 21] = new PVector(  C10,  0.0,  0.5 );
    vert[ 22] = new PVector(  C10,  0.0, -0.5 );
    vert[ 23] = new PVector(  C10,  0.0, -0.5 );
    vert[ 24] = new PVector( -C10,  0.0,  0.5 );
    vert[ 25] = new PVector( -C10,  0.0,  0.5 );
    vert[ 26] = new PVector( -C10,  0.0, -0.5 );
    vert[ 27] = new PVector( -C10,  0.0, -0.5 );
    vert[ 28] = new PVector(  0.5,  C10,  0.0 );
    vert[ 29] = new PVector(  0.5,  C10,  0.0 );
    vert[ 30] = new PVector(  0.5, -C10,  0.0 );
    vert[ 31] = new PVector(  0.5, -C10,  0.0 );
    vert[ 32] = new PVector( -0.5,  C10,  0.0 );
    vert[ 33] = new PVector( -0.5,  C10,  0.0 );
    vert[ 34] = new PVector( -0.5, -C10,  0.0 );
    vert[ 35] = new PVector( -0.5, -C10,  0.0 );
    vert[ 36] = new PVector(  -C1,  -C7,  -C8 );
    vert[ 37] = new PVector(  -C1,  -C7,   C8 );
    vert[ 38] = new PVector(  -C1,   C7,  -C8 );
    vert[ 39] = new PVector(  -C1,   C7,   C8 );
    vert[ 40] = new PVector(   C1,  -C7,  -C8 );
    vert[ 41] = new PVector(   C1,  -C7,   C8 );
    vert[ 42] = new PVector(   C1,   C7,  -C8 );
    vert[ 43] = new PVector(   C1,   C7,   C8 );
    vert[ 44] = new PVector(  -C8,  -C1,  -C7 );
    vert[ 45] = new PVector(  -C8,  -C1,   C7 );
    vert[ 46] = new PVector(  -C8,   C1,  -C7 );
    vert[ 47] = new PVector(  -C8,   C1,   C7 );
    vert[ 48] = new PVector(   C8,  -C1,  -C7 );
    vert[ 49] = new PVector(   C8,  -C1,   C7 );
    vert[ 50] = new PVector(   C8,   C1,  -C7 );
    vert[ 51] = new PVector(   C8,   C1,   C7 );
    vert[ 52] = new PVector(  -C7,  -C8,  -C1 );
    vert[ 53] = new PVector(  -C7,  -C8,   C1 );
    vert[ 54] = new PVector(  -C7,   C8,  -C1 );
    vert[ 55] = new PVector(  -C7,   C8,   C1 );
    vert[ 56] = new PVector(   C7,  -C8,  -C1 );
    vert[ 57] = new PVector(   C7,  -C8,   C1 );
    vert[ 58] = new PVector(   C7,   C8,  -C1 );
    vert[ 59] = new PVector(   C7,   C8,   C1 );
    vert[ 60] = new PVector(  -C0,  0.0,  -C2 );
    vert[ 61] = new PVector(  -C0,  0.0,   C2 );
    vert[ 62] = new PVector(   C0,  0.0,  -C2 );
    vert[ 63] = new PVector(   C0,  0.0,   C2 );
    vert[ 64] = new PVector(  -C2,  -C0,  0.0 );
    vert[ 65] = new PVector(  -C2,   C0,  0.0 );
    vert[ 66] = new PVector(   C2,  -C0,  0.0 );
    vert[ 67] = new PVector(   C2,   C0,  0.0 );
    vert[ 68] = new PVector(  0.0,  -C2,  -C0 );
    vert[ 69] = new PVector(  0.0,  -C2,   C0 );
    vert[ 70] = new PVector(  0.0,   C2,  -C0 );
    vert[ 71] = new PVector(  0.0,   C2,   C0 );
    vert[ 72] = new PVector(  -C5,  -C4,  -C9 );
    vert[ 73] = new PVector(  -C5,  -C4,   C9 );
    vert[ 74] = new PVector(  -C5,   C4,  -C9 );
    vert[ 75] = new PVector(  -C5,   C4,   C9 );
    vert[ 76] = new PVector(   C5,  -C4,  -C9 );
    vert[ 77] = new PVector(   C5,  -C4,   C9 );
    vert[ 78] = new PVector(   C5,   C4,  -C9 );
    vert[ 79] = new PVector(   C5,   C4,   C9 );
    vert[ 80] = new PVector(  -C9,  -C5,  -C4 );
    vert[ 81] = new PVector(  -C9,  -C5,   C4 );
    vert[ 82] = new PVector(  -C9,   C5,  -C4 );
    vert[ 83] = new PVector(  -C9,   C5,   C4 );
    vert[ 84] = new PVector(   C9,  -C5,  -C4 );
    vert[ 85] = new PVector(   C9,  -C5,   C4 );
    vert[ 86] = new PVector(   C9,   C5,  -C4 );
    vert[ 87] = new PVector(   C9,   C5,   C4 );
    vert[ 88] = new PVector(  -C4,  -C9,  -C5 );
    vert[ 89] = new PVector(  -C4,  -C9,   C5 );
    vert[ 90] = new PVector(  -C4,   C9,  -C5 );
    vert[ 91] = new PVector(  -C4,   C9,   C5 );
    vert[ 92] = new PVector(   C4,  -C9,  -C5 );
    vert[ 93] = new PVector(   C4,  -C9,   C5 );
    vert[ 94] = new PVector(   C4,   C9,  -C5 );
    vert[ 95] = new PVector(   C4,   C9,   C5 );
    vert[ 96] = new PVector(   C6,   C6,   C6 );
    vert[ 97] = new PVector(   C6,   C6,   C6 );
    vert[ 98] = new PVector(   C6,   C6,  -C6 );
    vert[ 99] = new PVector(   C6,   C6,  -C6 );
    vert[100] = new PVector(   C6,  -C6,   C6 );
    vert[101] = new PVector(   C6,  -C6,   C6 );
    vert[102] = new PVector(   C6,  -C6,  -C6 );
    vert[103] = new PVector(   C6,  -C6,  -C6 );
    vert[104] = new PVector(  -C6,   C6,   C6 );
    vert[105] = new PVector(  -C6,   C6,   C6 );
    vert[106] = new PVector(  -C6,   C6,  -C6 );
    vert[107] = new PVector(  -C6,   C6,  -C6 );
    vert[108] = new PVector(  -C6,  -C6,   C6 );
    vert[109] = new PVector(  -C6,  -C6,   C6 );
    vert[110] = new PVector(  -C6,  -C6,  -C6 );
    vert[111] = new PVector(  -C6,  -C6,  -C6 );
    // set faces
    faces[ 0] = new int[] { 60,   0,  17,  74, 100,  82 };
    faces[ 1] = new int[] { 60,  82,  20,  44,  97,  36 };
    faces[ 2] = new int[] { 60,  36,  12,   2,  16,  38 };
    faces[ 3] = new int[] { 60,  38, 101,  46,  21,  80 };
    faces[ 4] = new int[] { 60,  80,  96,  72,  13,   0 };
    faces[ 5] = new int[] { 61,   1,  15,  73,  98,  81 };
    faces[ 6] = new int[] { 61,  81,  22,  47, 103,  39 };
    faces[ 7] = new int[] { 61,  39,  18,   3,  14,  37 };
    faces[ 8] = new int[] { 61,  37,  99,  45,  23,  83 };
    faces[ 9] = new int[] { 61,  83, 102,  75,  19,   1 };
    faces[10] = new int[] { 62,   2,  12,  76, 104,  84 };
    faces[11] = new int[] { 62,  84,  25,  50, 109,  42 };
    faces[12] = new int[] { 62,  42,  17,   0,  13,  40 };
    faces[13] = new int[] { 62,  40, 105,  48,  24,  86 };
    faces[14] = new int[] { 62,  86, 108,  78,  16,   2 };
    faces[15] = new int[] { 63,   3,  18,  79, 110,  87 };
    faces[16] = new int[] { 63,  87,  27,  49, 107,  41 };
    faces[17] = new int[] { 63,  41,  15,   1,  19,  43 };
    faces[18] = new int[] { 63,  43, 111,  51,  26,  85 };
    faces[19] = new int[] { 63,  85, 106,  77,  14,   3 };
    faces[20] = new int[] { 64,   4,  22,  81,  98,  89 };
    faces[21] = new int[] { 64,  89,  29,  52,  97,  44 };
    faces[22] = new int[] { 64,  44,  20,   5,  23,  45 };
    faces[23] = new int[] { 64,  45,  99,  53,  28,  88 };
    faces[24] = new int[] { 64,  88,  96,  80,  21,   4 };
    faces[25] = new int[] { 65,   5,  20,  82, 100,  90 };
    faces[26] = new int[] { 65,  90,  31,  55, 103,  47 };
    faces[27] = new int[] { 65,  47,  22,   4,  21,  46 };
    faces[28] = new int[] { 65,  46, 101,  54,  30,  91 };
    faces[29] = new int[] { 65,  91, 102,  83,  23,   5 };
    faces[30] = new int[] { 66,   6,  25,  84, 104,  92 };
    faces[31] = new int[] { 66,  92,  32,  57, 107,  49 };
    faces[32] = new int[] { 66,  49,  27,   7,  24,  48 };
    faces[33] = new int[] { 66,  48, 105,  56,  33,  93 };
    faces[34] = new int[] { 66,  93, 106,  85,  26,   6 };
    faces[35] = new int[] { 67,   7,  27,  87, 110,  95 };
    faces[36] = new int[] { 67,  95,  34,  58, 109,  50 };
    faces[37] = new int[] { 67,  50,  25,   6,  26,  51 };
    faces[38] = new int[] { 67,  51, 111,  59,  35,  94 };
    faces[39] = new int[] { 67,  94, 108,  86,  24,   7 };
    faces[40] = new int[] { 68,   8,  32,  92, 104,  76 };
    faces[41] = new int[] { 68,  76,  12,  36,  97,  52 };
    faces[42] = new int[] { 68,  52,  29,   9,  33,  56 };
    faces[43] = new int[] { 68,  56, 105,  40,  13,  72 };
    faces[44] = new int[] { 68,  72,  96,  88,  28,   8 };
    faces[45] = new int[] { 69,   9,  29,  89,  98,  73 };
    faces[46] = new int[] { 69,  73,  15,  41, 107,  57 };
    faces[47] = new int[] { 69,  57,  32,   8,  28,  53 };
    faces[48] = new int[] { 69,  53,  99,  37,  14,  77 };
    faces[49] = new int[] { 69,  77, 106,  93,  33,   9 };
    faces[50] = new int[] { 70,  10,  31,  90, 100,  74 };
    faces[51] = new int[] { 70,  74,  17,  42, 109,  58 };
    faces[52] = new int[] { 70,  58,  34,  11,  30,  54 };
    faces[53] = new int[] { 70,  54, 101,  38,  16,  78 };
    faces[54] = new int[] { 70,  78, 108,  94,  35,  10 };
    faces[55] = new int[] { 71,  11,  34,  95, 110,  79 };
    faces[56] = new int[] { 71,  79,  18,  39, 103,  55 };
    faces[57] = new int[] { 71,  55,  31,  10,  35,  59 };
    faces[58] = new int[] { 71,  59, 111,  43,  19,  75 };
    faces[59] = new int[] { 71,  75, 102,  91,  30,  11 };
  } //end SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron()

  public String name() {
    return "Small Hexagrammic Hexecontahedron";
  }

  public void render() {  
    if (nofill) {
      noFill();
    } else {
      fill(fc0, fc1, fc2, fc3);
    }

    if (nostroke) {
      noStroke();
    } else {
      stroke(sc0, sc1, sc2, sc3);
    }

    if (parentSphere) {
      //Get parent sphere radius
      r = radius + stray;
      //Convert spherical coordinates into Cartesian coordinates
      x = cos(theta) * sin(phi) * r;
      y = sin(theta) * sin(phi) * r;
      z = cos(phi) * r;
    }

    pushMatrix();
    translate(x, y, z);
    scale(scaleSize * zoom); 
    strokeWeight(sw);
    rotateX(rx);
    rotateY(ry);
    rotateZ(rz);
    for (int i = 0; i < FACES; i = i+1) {
      beginShape();
      for (int i2 = 0; i2 < VERTICES; i2 = i2+1) {
        vertex(vert[faces[i][i2]].x,vert[faces[i][i2]].y,vert[faces[i][i2]].z);
      } // end for
      endShape(CLOSE);
    } // end for 
    popMatrix();
  } //end render()

} //end class SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron
```

It's not very elegant code-wise but works fine. It renders rotating complex (meaning many faces) polyhedrons to the screen. Each time you click it adds 5 new rotating polyhedron objects. Once you have 20-25 objects it starts to bog down, meaning the frames/sec drop and it looks jumpy.

I've been reading about threading in Processing/Java. So I started to think maybe I could split the total number of objects out to each core (my computer has 8). I saw [this example](http://www.camnewnham.com/threading-in-processing/). in particular.

Before I dive into this goose chase, does anyone know if threading would help in terms of animation speed? When I run a sketch normally does it always just use one core for the draw loop? Can threading spread out the object animation rendering over "idol" cores?

Comment: Threading can't improve the efficiency of the animation itself.  Your UI can only be updated from the main thread.  However, potentially (I've not really looked at your code), multithreading could improve the efficiency of calculating what needs to be animated.

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    toggle = false;
    spheres.get(0).addSphereItem("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron");
    spheres.get(1).addSphereItem("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron");
    spheres.get(2).addSphereItem("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron");
    spheres.get(3).addSphereItem("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron");
    spheres.get(4).addSphereItem("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron");
  } else if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    spheres.get(0).removeSphereItem();
    spheres.get(1).removeSphereItem();
    spheres.get(2).removeSphereItem();
    spheres.get(3).removeSphereItem();
    spheres.get(4).removeSphereItem();
  }
```

Don't just duplicate code like that.

Define a nice constant somewhere like `NUMBER_OF_SPHERES` or something related to why only 5 should be altered when clicking and use that in combination with a loop:

```
  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    toggle = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SPHERES; i++){
      spheres.get(i).addSphereItem("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron");
    }
  } else if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SPHERES; i++){
      spheres.get(i).removeSphereItem();
    }
  }
```

---

```
  if (type.equals("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron") == true) {
```

There is no need to check if something is true in an if statement like this. Just use `if (type.equals("SmallHexagrammicHexecontahedron"))`.